# what is ScriptResource.axd in the page load in web app?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, scriptresource.axd

What is ScriptResource.axd please find below in image.. is there anyway to remove it in the page request i have to pass my web page in PT test for 500ms.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't try to remove requests to those handlers without understanding why the requests are being made. A batch of ScriptResource.axd requests like that are usually due to ASP.NET controls registering includes to the scripts that they're dependent on, especially scripts for the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit controls.

If you want to minimize the number of individual requests without breaking your site, look into the ScriptManager's ability to combine multiple scripts into a single payload instead of individual scripts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488552(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

When ajax.net was introduced, files with extension .axd became popular. They are used to load resources such as javascripts or css but their content depends of course on their generator component.

Normally these files are associated with a httphandler and you can find them in the web.config and you can remove them from there:

```
<httpHandlers>
       <remove path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

This article may give you additional details:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx

Answer (score -2):

```
<httpHandlers>
        <remove path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET"/>
        <remove path="WebResource.axd" verb="POST"/>
        <remove path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET"/>
        <remove path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="POST"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```